# python: write the code in a better way?

Tags: python

here is an example code

```
    >>> array = [('The', 'Blue'),('men','Green'),('his','Red'),('beautiful','Yellow')]
    >>> z = [y for (x,y) in array]
    >>> l=[(z[i],z[i+1]) for i in range (len(z)-1)]
    >>> l
    >>> [('Blue', 'Green'), ('Green', 'Red'), ('Red', 'Yellow')]
```

Is there an alternative way to write this? say, maybe as a one-liner? The above code is better suited from running via a console.

Thanks all

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Thanks for the suggestion! Never knew that codereview existed.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Example code is off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: Looking at the related [help section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it seems quite alright. Let's take it to chat maybe. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulling all answers here together, this one-liner would work:

```
a = [('The', 'Blue'),('men','Green'),('his','Red'),('beautiful','Yellow')]

l = [(i[1],j[1]) for i,j in zip(a, a[1:])]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(l)
>>> [('Blue', 'Green'), ('Green', 'Red'), ('Red', 'Yellow')]
```

Just to explain, the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function takes two or more iterables and yields a tuple with the current item for each iterable, until the end of the iterable with the smallest length is reached.

Comment: That's much easier to read than my one-liner. :) And more efficient.

Comment: I agree with @PM2Ring that it is much easier to read. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function :

```
>>> array = [('The', 'Blue'),('men','Green'),('his','Red'),('beautiful','Yellow')]
>>> z = [y for (x,y) in array]
>>> zip(z,z[1:])
[('Blue', 'Green'), ('Green', 'Red'), ('Red', 'Yellow')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as a one-liner, but it looks pretty ugly.

```
a = [('The', 'Blue'),('men','Green'),('his','Red'),('beautiful','Yellow')]
l = zip(zip(*a)[1], zip(*a)[1][1:])
```

Two lines is *much* better:

```
colors = zip(*a)[1]
l = zip(colors, colors[1:])
```

---

FWIW, you can drop the parentheses in

```
z = [y for (x,y) in array]
```

And since you're not using `x` it's common to replace it with underscore:

```
z = [y for _,y in array]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the underscore tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [('The', 'Blue'),('men','Green'),('his','Red'),('beautiful','Yellow')]    

result = [(array[i][1], array[i+1][1])  for i in xrange(len(array)-1)]    
print result
```

Yields:

```
[('Blue', 'Green'), ('Green', 'Red'), ('Red', 'Yellow')]
```